# Using RequestURL to get to a different folder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I am using AS3 to make a game. I use RequestURL( filename ) to obtain the music I want to play. However, this means the music file has to be in the same folder as the .fla file. How can I use it to get a music file from a different folder? I don't really like having to leave my music outside of a Music folder or properly organised somehow....

EDIT: Should have mentioned this earlier. I tried to use simply something such as "whatever/filename", but I got this security error:

SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [flash.media.Sound.load()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#load%28%29) method yet?

```
//Make a new sound object
var s:Sound = new Sound();

//Load it
s.load(new URLRequest("someDifferentMusicFolder/loop.mp3"));

//Play it
s.play()
```

If you are loading it via another method, such as URLLoader + URLRequest, please post your code and we should be able to help a little better.

Generally speaking though URLRequests should allow you to specify different folders, so your problem may not be in the methodology you are using but may be in your implementation? Perhaps you are getting a security error? Whatever it may be, if you post your code we can help you narrow it down.

Comment: Yeah, indeed I am getting a security error, SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context. Should've added that to the question...

Comment: Strange enough I was poking around in the "normal" Flash IDE (not FlashBuilder which is my home) and ran into this error, did some Googling and found that for some reason if you declare the URLRequest first then use it it seemed to work, so just separating the one line above into two somehow made a difference.  Not claiming to understand why this is but it did make a difference: var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequst("someFolder/someFile.mp3"); s.load(urlRequest);  no guarantees but it worked for me.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you made it work. You should post what you did as as the answer to your own question and mark it as accepted, to close this question.

Comment: Dunno why I never accepted this answer :/ Oh well, better late than never